# JS closures - Passing a function to a child, how should the shared object be accessed

Tags: design, object-oriented, javascript, closures

I have a design and am wondering what the appropriate way to access variables is. I'll demonstrate with this example since I can't seem to describe it better than the title.

- `Term` is an object representing a bunch of time data (a repeating duration of time defined by a bunch of attributes)
- `Term` has some print functionality but does not implement the print functions itself, rather they are passed in as anonymous functions by the parent. This would be similar to how shaders can be passed to a renderer rather than defined by the renderer.
- A container (let's call it `Box`) has a `Schedule` object that can understand and use `Term` objects.
- `Box`  creates `Term` objects and passes them to `Schedule` as required. `Box` also defines the `print` functions stored in `Term`.
- A `print` function usually takes an argument and uses it to return a string based on that argument and `Term`'s internal data. Sometime the `print` function could also use data stored in `Schedule`, though. I'm calling this data `shared`.

So, the question is, what is the best way to access this `shared` data. I have a lot of options since JS has closures and I'm not familiar enough to know if I should be using them or avoiding them in this case.

Options:

1. Create a local "reference" (term used lightly) to the `shared` data (data is not a primitive) when defining the `print` function by accessing the `shared` data through `Schedule` from `Box`. Example:

   ```
   var schedule = function(){
       var sched = Schedule();
       var t1 = Term( function(x){   // Term.print()
                          return  (x + sched.data).format();
                    });
   };
   ```
2. Bind it to `Term` explicitly. (Pass it in `Term`'s constructor or something). Or bind it in `Sched` after `Box` passes it. And then access it as an attribute of `Term`.
3. Pass it in at the same time `x` is passed to the print function, (from sched). This is the most familiar way for my but it doesn't feel right given JS's closure ability.
4. Do something weird like `bind` some context and arguments to `print`.

I'm hoping the correct answer isn't purely subjective. If it is, then I guess the answer is just "do whatever works". But I feel like there are some significant differences between the approaches that could have a large impact when stretched beyond my small example.

**Edit**

I'll post the solution I'm using but I'd still welcome criticism:

All `print` functions take, as arguments, anything `term` doesn't own. This way, `term` is not coupled to `schedule` in any way (obviously `schedule` is still dependent on `term`, though). This allows `term` to be initialized/constructed anywhere without needing knowledge of schedule.

So, if `term` had an `init()` function it might take an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    inc: moment.duration(1,"d"),
    periods: 3,
    class: "long",
    text:"Weekly",
    pRange: moment.duration(7,'d'),
    //*...other attr*//
    printInc: function(increments,period){
        return moment(this.start).add(this.inc.product(increments)
              .add(this.startGap))
              .add(this.pRange.product(period))
              .format(DATEDISPLAYFORMAT);
    },
    printLabel: function(datetime){
        return (datetime).format(DATEDISPLAYFORMAT);
    }
}
```

Where increment, period, datetime would all be passed from whatever is using term's print methods (schedule in this case).

Comment: Could you be more specific on the relations between box, schedule and term? Is the relationship between schedule and term one to many? Is the box the owner of the schedule? Or is box just a factory?

Comment: @MarcodeJongh Box owns schedule and passes terms to it.`Term` is essentially a data structure with minor functionality and is used elsewhere in the app. The print functions are specific to schedule though. I'll update the question with the solution I'm using atm.

Comment: The solution you're using looks reasonable, although if the printing is specific to `Schedule`, why isn't it in the `Schedule` class rather than `Term`?